# How to set gradle JVM -X options (for gradle and compiling)?

Tags: gradle, jetty, bootclasspath

I would like to set the -Xbootclasspath for vm launched by gradle itself.  I am not sure if tests run in gradle VM or a new VM is spun up (if inside a VM, this would also get two birds stoned at the same time-pun intended).  My desire is bootclasspath for compiling and bootclasspath for running tests.

My end goal is I am trying to work with this jetty alpn jar

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-tests

It is not going so well so far though I do have eclipse compiling but can't seem to get the jetty providers to kick in.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add [compilation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) flags (for both main sources and test sources):

```groovy
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ['-Xbootclasspath...']
}
```

To add [test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) JVM flags (according to docs, tests are always run in one or more separate JVMs):

```groovy
test {
    jvmArgs = ['-Xbootclasspath...']
}
```